# Why can I not ping my EC2 instance when I've set up the VPC and EC2 via Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-vpc

I have a setup via Terraform which includes a VPC, a public subnet, and an EC2 instance with a security group. I am trying to ping the EC2 instance but get timeouts.

A few things I've tried to ensure:

- the EC2 is in the subnet, and the subnet is routed to internet via the gateway
- the EC2 has a security group allowing all traffic both ways
- the EC2 has an elastic IP
- The VPC has an ACL that is attached to the subnet and allows all traffic both ways

I'm not sure what I missed here.

My tf file looks like (edited to reflect latest changes):

```
resource "aws_vpc" "foobar" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "foobar_gateway" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.foobar.id
}

/*
Public subnet
*/
resource "aws_subnet" "foobar_subnet" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.foobar.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"
}

resource "aws_route_table" "foobar_routetable" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.foobar.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.foobar_gateway.id
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "foobar_routetable_assoc" {
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.foobar_subnet.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.foobar_routetable.id
}

/*
Web
*/
resource "aws_security_group" "web" {
  name = "vpc_web"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.foobar.id

  ingress {
    protocol    = -1
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    protocol    = -1
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_network_acl" "main" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.foobar.id
  subnet_ids = [aws_subnet.foobar_subnet.id]

  egress {
    protocol   = -1
    rule_no    = 100
    action     = "allow"
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    from_port  = 0
    to_port    = 0
  }

  ingress {
    protocol   = -1
    rule_no    = 100
    action     = "allow"
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    from_port  = 0
    to_port    = 0
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "web-1" {
  ami = "ami-0323c3dd2da7fb37d"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.foobar_subnet.id
  associate_public_ip_address = true
}

resource "aws_eip" "web-1" {
  instance = aws_instance.web-1.id
  vpc = true
}
```

Why can I not ping my EC2 instance when I've set up the VPC and EC2 via Terraform?

Comment: Can you please check your VPC ACL's manually via the AWS console and see if traffic is allowed. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable ping AWS EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61604861/unable-ping-aws-ec2-instance)

Comment: @EdcelCabreraVista it seems to be a different problem, as I do have security groups allowing all traffic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you adding the self parameter in your security group rule. The docs for terraform state that `If true, the security group itself will be added as a source to this ingress rule.` Which basically means that only that security group can access the instance. Please remove that and try.

EDIT: see comments below for steps that fixed the problem

Comment: This [example](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/default_security_group.html#example-config-to-deny-all-egress-traffic-allowing-ingress) in the Terraform docs — "default ingress rule to allow all traffic" has self = true... But I removed that, it still didn't work. I checked my AWS console and saw it didn't create any ingress/egress traffic rules, which could be the issue

Comment: Yes then the Network ACL might be the issue. From my understanding currently the SG doesn't allow your ip or anyone else to connect to your instance. So you will also need to remove that self param and add the ACL. Can you please add that and try.

Comment: I've removed self from the security group, added the ACL to allow all traffic, and attached the ACL to the subnet. Still not working

Comment: Have you not assigned any sg to your instance? Can you add this please vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.web.id] and try.

Comment: sogyals, that fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. I would suggest you look at separating your route's for your route table as it's easier to manage.

Comment: You should edit the answer to include what was actually needed here. Looking at the question's included code I don't see a reference to self at all but the instance is missing the security group configuration to actually attach the security group so your answer should just specify this.

Answer (score -2):

Allowing all the traffic through security group would not enable ping to the instance. You need to add a specific security rule - image shown below to enable the ping request.

[image: Security rule for enabling ping in EC2 instance]
Remember that AWS has made this rule separate to ensure that you know what you are doing. Being able to ping the instance from anywhere around the world leaves your instance vulnerable to people trying to find instance by bruteforcing various IP address.

Hence, it is advisable to carefully change this rule.

Comment: This isn't true at all. Setting the protocol to -1 allows all protocols including ICMP.